# All attempts to upload .ipa via iTMSTransporter failing with error in validateAssets method (1272)

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, app-store-connect-api

We publish many apps using our CI/CD system that makes use of the App Store Connect API and iTMSTransporter. Since around 9:00am on 19 Oct 2023 (Melbourne/Australia time UTC+10), all our attempts to upload our .ipa files using iTMSTransporter began failing.

The specific command line invocation is:

```
/usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -m upload -v eXtreme -f "/path/to/Bundle.itmsp" -jwt {jwt-here}
```

The error is occurring in the midst of the upload with the error message:

```
Apple's web service operation return value:
[2023-10-20 09:35:09 AEDT] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Errors = [An error occurred while trying to call the requested method validateAssets. (1272)]
[2023-10-20 09:35:09 AEDT] <main> DBG-X:   parameter RestartClient = false
[2023-10-20 09:35:09 AEDT] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ErrorCode = 1272
[2023-10-20 09:35:09 AEDT] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ErrorMessage = An error occurred while trying to call the requested method validateAssets. (1272)
[2023-10-20 09:35:09 AEDT] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Success = false
[2023-10-20 09:35:09 AEDT] <main> ERROR: An error occurred while trying to call the requested method validateAssets. (1272)
[2023-10-20 09:35:09 AEDT] <main> DBG-X: The error code is: 1272
```

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Is there any kind of work around or something we need to change?

Some other notes:

- The same .ipa files can be successfully uploaded manually using Transporter
- This is affecting apps built against both XCode 14 and XCode 15
- There was an outage shown on Apple's system status for a few hours that overlaps with this period, but Apple claim it was resolved 16 hours ago

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: We have the same problem. Manual uploads still work fine.

Comment: No progress at all unfortunately, despite hacking away for a couple of hours. I've raised this in Apple's developer forum and through that ridiculous Feedback Assistant, still nothing.

Comment: This issue just resolved by itself after a few days, we didn't change anything in our CD code. Another little glitch in Apple's API server code I guess.